# How to define a couchdb view that I can filter on attributes of different types of document?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

I have two types of document in a couch database. There are Events and Occurences. One Event has many Occurences.

**Event:**

```
{
  "_id": "49bb92b8896515a2994e524b38a041d3",
  "type": "Event",
  "eventID": 1234,
  "area": "m1"
}
```

**Occurence:**

```
{
  "_id": "49bb92b8896515a2994e524b38a041d4",
  "type": "Occurence",
  "occurenceID": 7890,
  "eventID": 1234,
  "date": "2013-01-01"
}
```

I need to find the count of occurences per date filtered by an area name and by a range of dates. In SQL, I'd use this query:

```
SELECT Date, count(*)
FROM Event INNER JOIN Occurence ON Occurence.EventID = Event.EventID
WHERE Event.Area = "m1"
AND Occurence.Date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-01'
GROUP BY Date
```

I don't mind executing more than one query but my database has over 300,000 occurence documents (and will grow 10 times that), so I need to get the results by tansfering as few documents as possible. The app that queries this couchdb is written with node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this would require two queries to get right, I think. You should consider denormalizing by copying the event area into the occurrence documents, that would make it a lot easier.

Comment: I tried to do it using two (or more) queries but I can't find the right solution. I tried by getting all eventIDs for an area and then filter the occurrences that match these IDs but that's too slow because there are 10,000 IDs. Can you provide the queries that you would use? Denormalization is indeed my last resort but I'd rather solve this using queries. I'm new to chouchdb and I take this as an exercise in writing complex queries too.

Comment: I think the multiple-queries approach would be way too slow given the data sizes you're mentioning. No need to be afraid of denormalization, this is how post-relational databases work.